# How to create a boost::tuple with the specified number of elements (of the same type)?

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

Assume that I have the following class definition:

```
template <unsigned int N>
class foo
{
    boost::tuples::tuple<...> bar;
};
```

Given the compile-time constant `N`, I would like to expand the type of `bar` to be a tuple that holds `N` elements of a specified type. That is, the type of `foo<2>::bar` would be `boost::tuples::tuple<T, T>`. I'm guessing that I can use [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual.html) for this, but I haven't figured out the exact sequence yet. I think I could do:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct type_repeater
{
    typedef typename boost::mpl::fold<
        boost::mpl::range_c<T, 0, N>,
        boost::mpl::vector<>,
        boost::mpl::push_back<_1, T>
    >::type type;
};
```

So then for instance `type_repeater<T, 2>::type` would be equivalent to `boost::mpl::vector<T, T>`. I'm just not sure how/if I can take that type list and inject it into the argument list of a tuple, like I want. Is this possible?

Comment: You don't need boost for this if you have access to C++11.  Would you be OK with a version that uses C++11 instead?

Comment: I'm open to hearing the best solution for either case, but in the end I will need at least a C++03 implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is totally doable with variadic templates and `std::tuple`, the best solution for what you want I think is to just use `std::array`. If you simply want a container with N instances of T, the `std::array` signature is already `template <typename T, std::size_t N> class array`. I think it fits your need exactly.

Having said that, if you really want `std::tuple` for some reason you can do it like so:

```
#include <tuple>

/* Forward declaration. */
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
class Tuple;

/* Convenience type alias. */
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
using TTuple = typename Tuple<N, T>::type;

/* Base case. */
template <typename T>
class Tuple<0, T> {
  public:

  using type = std::tuple<>;

}; // Tuple<0>

/* Recursive case. */
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
class Tuple {
  public:

  /* Note the use of std::declval<> here. */
  using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<std::tuple<T>>(),
                                       std::declval<TTuple<N - 1, T>>()));

};  // Tuple<N, T>

/* std::declval<> is necessary to support non default constructable classes. */
class NoDefault {
  public:

  NoDefault() = delete;

};  // Foo

/* Sample use. */
static_assert(std::is_same<TTuple<2, NoDefault>,
                           std::tuple<NoDefault, NoDefault>>::value, "");

int main() {}
```

**Note:** If you don't have access to C++11 but do have access to boost, `boost::array` and `boost::tuples::tuple` will do fine in lieu of `std::array` and `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a good minimal example using C++11

```
#include <tuple>
template <unsigned int N, typename T>
struct type_repeater {
  typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<T>(), typename type_repeater<N-1, T>::type())) type;
};

template <typename T>
struct type_repeater<0, T> {
  typedef decltype(std::tuple<>()) type;
};

int main() {
  type_repeater<3, float>::type asdf;
  std::get<0>(asdf);
  std::get<1>(asdf);
  std::get<2>(asdf);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm done screwing around with this answer I think.

Comment: This is fine, albeit it could be better since all it does is repeatedly concatenate tuples recursively.

Comment: This is the first way that came to mind, do you have any method in mind that doesn't use recursion?

Comment: @Rapptz: Link please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you explicitly ask for a way to make mpl::vector into a runtime container, I recommend you stay Boosty and use Fusion's [as_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/conversion/metafunctions/as_vector.html):

Given your initial example where you mol::fold to get an mpl::vector, you would then use:

```
boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<
    mpl::vector<T, T>
>::type;
```

To get a [Fusion Vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html), which seems to be what you want. [Boost Fusion](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/) fills the gap between the compile-time and runtime world.

Also, this is pre C++11, which is still important in many (maybe most?) projects.